# Go language's godoc on command prompt

Tags: windows, go, command-prompt

```
    godoc fmt
```

This command displays the documentation of fmt package. But this has a lot of content and does not support paging control(/p) of command prompt.

```
    godoc fmt /p
```

Please let me know how can I get paged documentation in command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
godoc fmt | more
```

[more](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true) is not specific for "godoc" and should work for the output of any command. press the spacebar to move to the next page.

Comment: How could I forget that. Thanks a lot.